# Simple search page PHP MySQL fulltext search

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

I'm building a search page on my website.

At first I looked at search engines but those require a VPS or dedicated server. I'm currently on a shared server.

So I tried MySQL fulltext search.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `deck_search_table`(
`id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
`index_date` INTEGER NOT NULL,
`user_id` INTEGER NOT NULL,
`username` VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
`deck_id` INTEGER NOT NULL,
`deck_title` VARCHAR(145) DEFAULT NULL,
`last_modified` INTEGER NOT NULL,
`card_one` TEXT NOT NULL,
`card_two` TEXT NOT NULL,
`card_three` TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
`card_count` INTEGER NOT NULL
)
ENGINE=MyISAM 
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


ALTER TABLE deck_search_table ADD FULLTEXT(card_one, card_two, card_three);
```

Here's what my table looks like. But I can't get it to work.
I put two rows in the database. One with `Fastidous` once and one with `Fastidous` twice. Then ran this

```
SELECT * FROM deck_search_table WHERE MATCH (card_one) AGAINST ('Fastidous')
```

Got zero results. I removed the one with two `Fastidous` words and it gave me a result.

But I'm not really sure how this works.

Basically, how do I perform a search?... and get back results that are organized from most relevant to least relevant?

Here's an example of what I'd like to do.

```
$timeVar = strtotime("Today");
$searchQuery = "Search for the goods Mister Search Engine";

SELECT * FROM deck_search_table WHERE last_modified >=$timeVar AND
MATCH (deck_title,card_one,card_two,card_three) AGAINST ($searchQuery)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add more rows. The engine `MyISAM` ignores the word if it occurs in more than 50% rows as noise. So either add more rows or change the engine to `InnoDB`.

Working examples:

InnoDB:

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/575c0d/2

MyISAM:

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/98579/1

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use `LIKE` and not `MATCH`.

```
SELECT * FROM deck_search_table WHERE deck_title LIKE $search_query OR card_one LIKE $search_query
```

(I only add card_one but that can be more)